# Aria role='Alert' not being seen by NVDA

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria

I have the following div tag:

```
<div id="ErrorMsg" 
      role="alert" 
      class="alert alert-error" 
      style="display:none;">
        Email or password incorrect
</div>
```

When I fire this jQuery it becomes visible, but is not announced as an alert.

```
$('#ErrorMsg').show();
```

This is added to the page after I do an isvalid check like so:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
        this, 
        GetType(), 
        "Error", 
        "$('#ErrorMsg').show();", 
        true);
```

I'm testing with NVDA, the page is an aspx page with an update panel.  I tried removing the panel but that doesn't seem to be the problem. Everything is working, just no notification of alert. The text boxes that are being checked have the describedby tags set and pointing to the div tags id.

Comment: What browser are you using? Different browsers support ARIA to different degrees, and you can often get different behavior with the same screenreader used against IE vs Firefox, for example.

Comment: I've test FF20, chrome, IE 8 - 10 and all are pretty consistent on this

Comment: There's a webaim thread similar to this going on

Answer (score 1):

I would say the problem is one of two things.

There are other DOM things that are happening and interrupting the alert before it is read. One solution for this is to use aria-live="rude" although this doesnt help NDVA as this is still non-interrupting.

You may be able to put focus on the element by using $('#ErrorMsg').focus(). You will also need to put an tabindex="0" on the element. e.g.

```
<div id="ErrorMsg"
      role="alert"
      tabindex="0"      
      class="alert alert-error" 
      style="display:block;">
        Email or password incorrect
</div>
```

The other problem may be that the page is refreshed by ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock (i'm not a .NET developer so I may be wrong). That being the case, the above solution should also work.

However if this approach works it is possible that a screen-reader user is then 'lost' as to where they are on the page. So you may need to change the ErrorMsg element into an  which links to the email or password input box.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't think 'rude' was a property name?  Will try it though.  As for the linking, I agree ... might have to change the div to a label and link it with a for attribute.  But the message text itself should let them know what the error is for.

Comment: You are right Greg, "rude" was removed from the spec in 2009 according to http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/introduction-to-wai-aria/ although still supported by some screen readers.